# Why I can't get the full document form array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document in stored in my collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2d"), 
  "companyId" : ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e"), 
   "descriptions" : [ 
                     { "id" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a"), "description" : "test" },
                     { "id" : ObjectId("570cd8164fff3a20f88c0dc9"), "description" : "test1" },
                     { "id" : ObjectId("570ce6ba4fff3a052c8c570f"), "description" : "etr" },
                     { "id" : ObjectId("570cf1b64fff3a1a14d71716"), "description" : "43" },
                     { "id" : ObjectId("570cf1b64fff3a1a14d71717"), "description" : "43" },
                     { "id" : ObjectId("570cf1b64fff3a1a14d71719"), "description" : "345" } 
                    ],
    "options" : [
                 { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a"), "description" : "test" },
                 { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a"), "description" : "test1" } 
                ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the objects from the `options` array that are matching the `descriptionId` and here is how I'm doing it

```
db.CustomFields.find({companyId: ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e")},{"options.descriptionId": ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a")})
```

But the result contains only the `descriptionId` - the `description` property is missing.

here is how the result looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2d"),
  "options" : [ 
               { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a") },
               { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a") } 
              ]
}
```

Why my query is not returning the full document from the array, but only a part of it? Can you give me a push?

**EDIT**

This is what I'm expecting to get from the query

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2d"),
  "options" : [ 
               { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a", "description" : "test") },
               { "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a", "description" : "test1") } 
              ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the other query with `"options.descriptionId"` together with the `companyId` query and use projection to return just the array you want.

The following shows this:

```
db.customFields.find(
    {
        "companyId": ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e"),
        "options.descriptionId": ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a")
    }, 
    { "options": 1 }
);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2d"),
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a"),
            "description" : "test"
        }, 
        {
            "descriptionId" : ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a"),
            "description" : "test1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But, how can I get all the matching documents at once?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your expected result is?

Comment: @Slim I had misunderstood your question. All you need is just projection on the `options` field, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: Whoa! I knew that I was missing a really small part here! HUGE thanks for the help! You saved many hours of my time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

db.CustomFields.find({companyId: ObjectId("570269639caabe24e4e4043e"),"options.descriptionId": ObjectId("5707b95b8415b224a48a0b2a")})

Comment: This returns the whole document... I need only the options array

Comment: you asked 'Why my query is not returning the full document"...so I given this...let me check again... Do you want only Options array in the result?